# Is it more difficult to create higher energy photons, given there is excess available energy?

Tags: atomic-physics, x-ray-crystallography

I'm not talking about pair production, I mean a single photon created from an energy transition between two electron shells.

I'm studying K(alpha) and K(beta) fluorescence transitions in metals, and alpha transitions are more likely to occur than beta.

Is this because the electron drops down a smaller energy gap? If so, what makes a lower energy photon more desirable for the electron? Even if a mid-level electron drops down to fill the vacancy, this results in a new vacancy, needing to be filled by a higher-level electron, and so on. Why wouldn't a higher energy electron drop down, resulting in a higher energy photon?

I can't understand why one is more energetically favorable than the other, since both situations result in the same loss of energy (don't they?).

Thanks!

Comment: This to be really answered needs somebody working on this or similar. The general answer is that in the quantum mechanical frame in which these observations belong it is not only energy that decides the probability of transitions from one energy level to the other. Quantum numbers play a definitive role in the wave function , spin particularly in this case. Suppression in the probability of emitting or absorbing a photon comes from the probability given by the square of the wave function. So it is not only just energetically favorable, dropping from higher to lower energy levels.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment by Anna said, spontaneous emission does not necessarily depends on differences in energy. Even worse, spontaneous transitions were not explainable within the framework of semiclassical quantum theory, in which the atomic levels were quantized, but the electromagnetic field was not. In the absence of a quantized electromagnetic field, the excited state atom can not decay to the ground state. In order to explain spontaneous transitions, quantum mechanics must be extended to a quantum field theory, wherein the electromagnetic field is quantized at every point in space. The quantum field theory of electrons and electromagnetic fields is known as quantum electrodynamics. For more details about spontaneous emission see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_emission)